# Connecting Spring to Existing JDBC Connection

Tags: spring, jdbc

I've followed [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/#initial) through Spring's docs. It's nice, but I can not find anything online (and current) that shows how to connect to an existing `DataSource` through JDBC using Spring. Where can I configure this connection? This tutorial only shows how to create one (but where exactly is it even doing that?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your how-to link, you can see:

```
 Spring Boot spots H2, an in-memory relational database engine, 
 and automatically creates a connection. Because we are using
 spring-jdbc, Spring Boot automatically creates a JdbcTemplate.
 The @Autowired JdbcTemplate field automatically loads it and 
 makes it available.
```

You can bypass the default `DataSource` by adding `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})` to your `Application` class. [This link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-configure-datasource) provides more detail on setting up a `DataSource` in Spring Boot.

...and the other sections are pretty useful too!

Answer (score 1):

You are using Spring boot which contains embedded databases, in this case H2 database (check line "Spring Boot spots H2, an in-memory relational database engine, and automatically creates a connection.")
To provide custom connection and configure DataSource see this section https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html